# prime number function.

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $f$ be a following function :
${ f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{P} }$

${ f(n) = p_n }$, where $p_n$ is n-th prime number.

I want to prove or find a proof that ${ f \in \Theta\left(n\log\left(n\right)\right) }$ (using Big-Theta notation) which seems correct by empirical evidence:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ylpnljuh1y

If I assume that ${ \Pi \in \Theta(\frac{x}{ln{x}})  }$, where $\Pi$ is a prime-counting function it seems me easy to prove because inverse of ${n\log{n}}$ is ${\frac{x}{W(x)}}$, where $W$ is lambert W-function. I can prove that ${\frac{x}{W(x)} \in \Theta(\frac{x}{ln{x}}) }$ but I can't find proof or prove that ${ \Pi \in \Theta(\frac{x}{ln{x}})  }$. Can anyone help me?

I apologize for not being word-perfect in English.

Comment: $\pi(x) \in \Theta(x/\log x)$ is a result by Chebyshev.

Comment: This is the prime number theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem

Comment: This is [Chebyshev's Theorem](https://holdenlee.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/6-2.pdf).

Comment: It is all what i need. Thanks for answers.